# One remote RDP user often gets stuck on "Please wait for the local session manager" from a shared virtual Windows Server 2019; others work

Tags: rdp, windows-10, connection, windows-server-2019

The server is a shared virtual server slice running Windows Server 2019. (Set up by InterServer - I'm the software developer of the customer.)

A remote Windows 10 computer in location A usually connects to the server via RDP without problems, but occasionally (was every few weeks, months ago, but for the last several weeks it is at least once per week) it starts failing to connect for an hour or so.

The messages seen include:

- "Please wait for the Local Session Manager" (forever, and sometimes
  after having been connected for some minutes) <-- This is the most
  common.
- "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer"
- "Reconnecting - The connection has been lost. Attempting to reconnect
  to your session..." (never reconnects)
- "Your Remote Desktop Services session has ended."

A remote Windows (8?) computer in location A used until a few months ago (retired because remote printing wouldn't work), seemed to be able to reliably connect to the server via RDP and stay connected.

A remote Windows 7 computer in location B has pretty much always been able to RDP connect to the server without problems, even when the computer at location A is unable to connect.

I have searched for and read articles about these messages, but I have not seen anything in them that would explain why when the Win 10 machine gets the "Please Wait for the Local Session Manager" message, then the location B Win 7 machine can RDP in fine, and if I reboot the server, then usually the Win 10 machine has no problems, at least until the next day.

Update: In the months since I posted this, the situation has improved, with location A still occasionally having this same problem, but much less frequently. This leads me to believe that it either something to do with Windows updates, and/or with other conditions on the shared server, since it is not still a frequent problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the temporary solution. You may reboot remote host without RDP-login to it from other windows machine in domain. 192.168.111.11 is the remote IP address:

```
shutdown.exe /r /f /m \\192.168.111.11 /t 0
```

/r - reboot
/f - force processes to close
/m \\host - remote action on other host
/t 00 - wait 0 sec

Comment: Thanks. That answer may be useful to others. However, in my situation, I am able to reliably RDP to the server from location B. I can reset it that way, which seems to almost always restore location A's ability to RDP to the server.